# properly share pycharm settings in git

Tags: python, git, pycharm

We have a very large and complicated python environment that is shared with many developers.

To set it up, there is a need to configure a lot of things in pycharm(e.g. source folders).

In order to not instruct everyone cloning the repo to have to go to pycharm settings and modify it, I wanted to share the pycharm settings inside git.

There's a nice article about it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/sharing-project-settings.html) where essentially you add the .idea folder to git and just ignore user specific settings files like workspace.xml.

This works fine, however some things that are specific to user are stored in global files that are supposed to be shared. One example is the project interpreter path.

Now, if the file is changed, then every user will get a changed file in git and would need to commit it and that's not what I want.

I thought about using "git update-index --skip-worktree" on these files after the clone, which "hides" the changes to the files that the user does, but then it is impossible to change branches easily.

Do you have any easy solution for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: you are biding each person to pycharm which in my opinion is not right, better create an automatic environment setup in bash or any else and let others choose their way to code

Comment: If I let everyone choose their own IDE, the problem gets even worse. I would need to write a wiki article about setting up each IDE.

Comment: Or, provide a "set up IDE" set-of-files, per IDE. Describe the supported IDEs: "here is my list of supported IDEs: * pycharm. Yes, this is a one element list. To add more IDEs, update the wiki." :-)

Comment: True, but this is not what I asked. Suppose we're using pycharm, I'm failing to properly share the settings...